# Angularjs $timeout doesn't work at first minute

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I was trying to execute some code in the first second after every new Minute in my AngularJs Website.
Now i got the following code:

```
let msToNextMin: number = moment().endOf('minute').diff(moment());
console.log("msToNextMin: " + msToNextMin);
this.$timeout(() => {
    this.$interval(() => {               
        console.log(moment().toString() + "New Minute started now");
    }, 60000);
}, msToNextMin + 1000);
```

This code works how it is **but** it leaves the first minute out.

---

If I start the code at:

> 13:09:33 output will be:

```
msToNextMin: 27215
```

> that's all right but the next output is always:

```
Thu Oct 20 2016 13:11:01 GMT+0200New Minute started now
```

Somebody has an explanation for this issue?

Comment: Are you initializing at first time when page loading?

Comment: Can you prived a fiddle?

Comment: @JigarPrajapati yes but i mean it doesn't matter...

Comment: i agree with you , but just want to confirm something, that was the reason only

Comment: is the interval setting a timeout before it calls itself?